# Avoid duplicate code when mapping an array to Controls

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net

I have a array of bit which has size of 8, I traverse the array of bit and update the checkbox of each corresponding bit based on whether the bit is zero or not. So far I have the following:

```
        Dim btArr6 As BitArray = New BitArray(8)
        ......
        ......
        If btArr6(0) = True Then
             d2b0.Checked = True
        End If
        If btArr6(1) = True Then
            d2b1.Checked = True
        End If
        If btArr6(2) = True Then
            d2b2.Checked = True
        End If
        If btArr6(3) = True Then
            d2b3.Checked = True
        End If
        If btArr6(4) = True Then
            d2b4.Checked = True
        End If
        If btArr6(5) = True Then
            d2b5.Checked = True
        End If
        If btArr6(6) = True Then
            d2b6.Checked = True
        End If
        If btArr6(7) = True Then
            d2b7.Checked = True
        End If
```

I think it has duplicate code.  I am thinking it would be better if I have something like d2b & I.  However it is not right since it is not string. Any idea on how could I get rid of duplicate code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least, this would be shorter:

```
d2b0.Checked = btArr6(0)
d2b1.Checked = btArr6(1)
...
```

> Your code wont ever UNcheck the controls since it only checks/acts on one state.  That isnt usually the case for these things, but if it is, the single line `If` can be used:

```
If btArr6(0) Then d2b0.Checked = True
```

When an array or `List` maps to a set of Controls, create/maintain an array of those controls so you can just use a loop.  If used more than once, you can declare and build a single array:

```
Public Class Form1
    ' declaration
    Private d2b As CheckBox()
```

Important: Do not initialize in the declaration (i.e. list the controls) - they  do not exist yet. Initialize it somewhere like form load:

```
d2b = New CheckBox() {CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3, CheckBox4}

' elsewhere to use it:

For n As Int32 = 0 To d2b.Count - 1
    d2b(n).Checked = btArr6(n)
Next
```

**Again**, use an `If` statement if you never want the checks to be UNchecked via the loop. The same method(s) will work to map an array of Booleans:

```
Private boolAry(8) As Boolean
...
myChecks(n).Checked = boolAry(n)
```

In fact, the same *concept* can be used to map data from any array to set of controls.

Comment: What a solution!! Thank you again Plutonix.  You have helped me many times and I really appreciate it

Comment: You were right that when you find yourself repeating code or code patterns, there is almost always a better way.  It is called the DRY principle - Dont Repeat Yourself

Comment: Your original code never UNchecks them - it only acted on True, so you might still need to check the state if that was on purpose.

Comment: I just tried my program again, it does not work when I initialized d2b in the load(it returns null).  It never happens before.  So I have to initialize it right before I use it.  Very weird.

Answer (score -2):

This would be the easiest way to avoid duplication with your existing code:

```
Dim btArr6 As BitArray = New BitArray(8)

Dim d2b = { d2b0, d2b1, d2b2, d2b3, d2b4, d2b5, d2b6, d2b7 }

For i = 0 To 7
    If btArr6(i) = True Then
        d2b(i).Checked = True
    End If
Next
```